# How to theme jquery-ui with npm and requires?

Tags: node.js, jquery-ui, npm, webpack

**Is it possible to theme jquery-ui via npm?**
Or do we still have to go through the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download)?

The [jquery-ui package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui) has the default theme included at:
`./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/*.css`.

If we `require('jquery-ui')` that won't load any css styling as well, right?

**Do we need to `require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css')`?**
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

1. ## Is it possible to theme jquery-ui via npm?

   Yes, you can use jquery theme package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui-themeroller)).

   `npm i jquery-ui-themeroller`.

   And import it

   `require('./jquery-ui-themes/themes/dot-luv/theme.css');`

   `dot-luv` is the name of theme.

   Here is [official document](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller), not only theme list also tool for customize theme.

   Remember to import jquery css file first `require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css')`
2. ## If we `require('jquery-ui')` that won't load any css styling as well, right?

   Yes, you should import `require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css');` to get the style file.
3. ## Do we need to `require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css')`?

   It is the simplest way to get all widgets style. But in most case we only need several widget.

   That say we want `datepicker` only, we should import css file by

   ```
   require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css');
   require('./jquery-ui/themes/base/datepicker.css');
   ```

   And now you can use your own theme in the end.

Answer (score 0):

To use a `jquery-ui` component from node_modules you need to import all JS and CSS. For example I use `sortable` in my webpack/typescript project like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/sortable.css'
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css'
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable'

$('ol.sortable').sortable({ ... })
```

Similarly with nodejs:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css')
require('jquery-ui/themes/base/sortable.css')
require('jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css')
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable')
```